# Showing two vectors {$v_1$,$v_2$} is a basis for $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: vector-spaces

If I have two vectors $\{v_1,v_2\}$ -> $\begin{pmatrix}-5\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-2\\1\end{pmatrix}$

And I want to show that they are a basis for $\Bbb R^2$, can I simply show that the determinant is not equal to $0$ that the inverse does exist?

$\therefore$ They are linearly independent and form a basis?

Comment: Yes, you can show that the determinant is not zero. In this case, the determinant is $(-5)*1 - (2*-2) = -1 \neq  0$, so this forms a basis.

Comment: check out Invertible Matrix Theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v^1,v^2$ are linearly-independent then $xv^1+yv^2 = 0$ implies $x = y = 0$. This is the same as saying the kernel of the map;

$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} -5 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\\$$

is trivial. If the determinant of the matrix above (call it $A$) is non-zero then it is invertible and so $A\vec{x} = \vec{0} \Rightarrow A^{-1}A\vec{x} = I \vec{x} = \vec{x} = \vec{0}$, so yes it is enough to show the determinant is non-zero.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!
I wasn't sure if I needed to prove that there was also a valid inverse.

Comment: Yeah np. In this case the inverse is actually easily computed. You just swap $a_{11},a_{22}$, negate $a_{12},a_{21}$ and then multiply by 1/det(A) (or something like that). Also, if this answers suffices for you, you can accept and that way the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

For two vectors linear dependence is the same as saying that  one vector is a scalar multiple of the other.
This helps us (in some cases) to decide without determinant calculation.

For example $(72,0,16,32,77)$ and $(-48, 11, 60, 36,108)$ are linearly independent. How? The second component is zero in the first vector. So any multiple of the first vector should have a zero in the same slot. As the second vector has 11 in that slot these two vectors are linearly independent.

$(2,7,23)$ and $(18,40,-22)$ are linearly independent. How? If the first vector is multiplied by a positive scalar we cannot get $-22$ in the third slot; if multiplied by a negative scalar .... you get the drift, I suppose.